# catch the click event on a specific mesh in the renderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I set a canvas renderer which contain two meshs (cubes). What i need to do is to *`catch the click event on each cube`* to call the convenient method for it.

So far, i could catch the click event on all the renderer, means when i click on cube1 and cube2, the click belong the same 'cause it's bound to the `renderer` :)

My question is, how  to bind the click event on each cube?

My relevant code is the following:

```
            //dom
    var containerPopUp=document.getElementById('popup');
    //renderer
    var rendererPopUp = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    rendererPopUp.setSize(420,200);

    containerPopUp.appendChild(rendererPopUp.domElement);
    //Scene
    var scenePopUp = new THREE.Scene();
    //Camera
    var cameraPopUp = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50,60/60,1,1000);

    cameraPopUp.position.z = 220;
    cameraPopUp.position.y =  20;
    //
    scenePopUp.add(cameraPopUp);

    //Add texture for the cube
    //Use image as texture
    var img2D = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ //CHANGED to MeshBasicMaterial
    map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/2d.png') 
    });
    img2D.map.needsUpdate = true; //ADDED
    //Add Cube
    var cubeFor2D = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(40,80,40),img2D);
    cubeFor2D.position.x =- 60;
    cubeFor2D.position.y = 20;

    scenePopUp.add(cubeFor2D);
    //
    var img3D = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ //CHANGED to MeshBasicMaterial
    map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/3d.png') 
    });
    img3D.map.needsUpdate = true;
    var cubeFor3D = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(40,80,40),img3D);
    cubeFor3D.position.x = 60;
    cubeFor3D.position.y=20;

    scenePopUp.add(cubeFor3D);
    //
    rendererPopUp.render(scenePopUp,cameraPopUp);
    //
    animate();

    rendererPopUp.domElement.addEventListener('click',testCall,false);//Here the click event is bound on the whole renderer, means what ever object in the renderer is clicked, the testCall method is called.
```

As you can see, cubeFor2D and cubeFor3D are contained in the renderer. I need to bind the click event on each mesh. I tried this with the `threex.domevent.js`:

```
var meshes  = {};
        meshes['mesh1'] = cubeFor2D;
        meshes['mesh1'].on('mouseover', function(event){

              //response to click...
              console.log('you have clicked on cube 2D');

        });
```

But it doesn't work, in the console, i got this error:

```
TypeError: meshes.mesh1.on is not a function
```

Of course, i included the API source code file:

```
    <script src="threex.domevent.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think threex.domevent.js is quite outdated, infact it's 9 month old.

Comment: I think so too. I try to perform my goal with pure Three.js. Forget about `threex.domevent.js` API. Do you have any suggestion how to do so with Three.js ?

Comment: I think this could be a good start [http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html](http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can generate a callback like this. First define your callback function for each object:

```
mesh.callback = function() { console.log( this.name ); }
```

Then follow the standard picking pattern:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects ); 

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        intersects[0].object.callback();

    }

}
```

EDIT: updated to three.js r.70

Comment: Any way to detect which side of cube got clicked and what was the x,y of click on that side?

Comment: Please make a new post if you have a question.

Comment: I have a door that has several elements like hinges, screws, anchors, pivots etc. so on click i dont get the accurate ones, it maybe because they are overlapping.  what can be the way to sort that out ? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user2906608 You need to make a new post if you have a question.

Comment: Note - if the three canvas does not cover the whole screen, set the mouse event on `renderer.domElement` and use `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a click handler

   ```
   window.addEventListener('click', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
   ```
2. Define the function onDocumentMouseDown, note that raycaster the difference in above answer is the index position of the object clicked!

   ```
   var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
   var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
   function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
   mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
   raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
   console.log(scene.children);
   var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
   console.log(intersects[1]);
   if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
       intersects[1].object.callback();
   }}
   ```
3. Define the Mesh object

   ```
   var mesh_menu_title = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_menu, materials_menu);
   mesh_menu_title.name = 'select_lang';
   mesh_menu_title.callback = function() { select_language();}
   scene.add(mesh_menu_title);
   ```
4. define the callback function

   ```
   function select_language(){
   var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName("select_lang"); 
   scene.remove( selectedObject );
   var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName("start");
   scene.remove( selectedObject );
   var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName("menu");
   scene.remove( selectedObject );
   }
   ```

So this code above will handle specific object clicked inside my canvas, then callback a function, the "mesh.callback" and it will remove some scene childs from the canvas.

It doesn't work if you use intersects[0].object.callback(); because at the index 0 the stored object are the vertices.