# Clickable mesh with THREE.lod

Tags: three.js

I for now work on a 3D engine for an amateur video game, and i want to add to him tons of features to get the best performances & gameplay. But i've got serious problems to get an "on click event" with lod meshes.

For the "lod" part, no problem for now, he's integrated, but i found no solution to apply that exemple with him :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808987/3379444

Did i must push the "lod" object, or every mesh individually ?

a part of my code :

```
var i, j, mesh, lod;
for ( j = 0; j <= 42; j++) {

lod = new THREE.LOD();

    //Here, it's just var for place my mesh into a circle
rayonSysteme = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 2500;
angleSysteme = Math.random() * 360; 

for ( i = 0; i < geometry.length; i ++ ) {

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry[ i ][ 0 ], material );
    mesh.scale.set( 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 );
    mesh.updateMatrix();
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            //Callback here ? 
    mesh.callback = function() { console.log( this.name ); }
    lod.addLevel( mesh, geometry[ i ][ 1 ] );

}

lod.position.x = rayonSysteme * Math.cos(angleSysteme);
lod.position.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)-500;
lod.position.z = rayonSysteme * Math.sin(angleSysteme);
    //Or here ? 
lod.updateMatrix();
lod.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

gravity = drawCircle("XZ", 64, 500, 360);
gravity.position.x = lod.position.x;
gravity.position.y = lod.position.y;
gravity.position.z = lod.position.z;


scene.add( lod );
//objects.push( lod );
scene.add( gravity );
};
```

Comment: Can you show a very simple live example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: My main workspace is here : http://lesfougeresdelulu.com/Moteur3D/ this is where i try to get my engine cleaner as possible (but it's still rookie's sorcery for now).

And here, my try with the mrdoob advices : http://lesfougeresdelulu.com/Moteur3D/save2.html (the balls are on the left and the right, i don't change the génération code so it's random)

My goal is to get this feature, on the main code, but it's still in work for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Raycaster` will test the mesh that should be used based on the distance to the ray origin.

This is the relevant code inside `Raycaster`:

```
} else if ( object instanceof THREE.LOD ) {

    matrixPosition.setFromMatrixPosition( object.matrixWorld );
    var distance = raycaster.ray.origin.distanceTo( matrixPosition );

    intersectObject( object.getObjectForDistance( distance ), raycaster, intersects );

}
```