# Is there a way to bind a click event to an object in Three.js

Tags: three.js

In Three.js, is there a way to bind a click event to an object so that when the object is clicked the contents of a div element are updated? Something like this (note I'm using jQuery as well):

```
mesh.click(function(){
  $('#myDiv').html('Hello Goober');
});
```

I'm also using the OrbitControls, which allows user to left-click+drag the scene to rotate it and right-click+drag the scene to pan. I'd like to keep that functionality while also handling a single click on the mesh as described above.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800150/catch-the-click-event-on-a-specific-mesh-in-the-renderer

Answer (score 1):

An example of this by Lee Stemkoski

This sends a ray through a mesh, selects the face. It's possible to use bouning boxes, bounding spheres, proxy meshes etc.

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Click.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `THREE.Raycaster` for picking and more.