# Clickable Sprite Labels?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I’ve been playing with sprite text labels and more specifically with this example: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html
and I was just wondering if it is possible to somehow assign an id to a sprite variable so that when the sprite is clicked on, an action occurs?

In my example “Hello“ and “World” are two separate variables:

```
var spriteHello = makeTextSprite ( "Hello", 
                  { fontsize: 24, borderColor: {r:255, g:0, b:0, a:1.0},
                  backgroundColor: {r:255, g:100, b:100, a:0.8} }  );
spriteHello.position.set(100,55,55);
scene.add( spriteHello );

var spriteWorld = makeTextSprite ( "World", 
                  { fontsize: 32, fontface: "Georgia", 
                  borderColor: {r:0, g:0, b:255, a:1.0} } );
spriteWorld.position.set(55,105,55);
scene.add( spriteWorld );
```

Or is there another way of doing this with using this specific example?
Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800150/catch-the-click-event-on-a-specific-mesh-in-the-renderer

Comment: Sorry, I can't write your code for you, but here is a start: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z4sK/13/. You need to do the rest yourself. :-)

Comment: Haha yes that's my JSFiddle code, I posted it earlier but had it deleted for now because I'm working on it. When I find a solution, I'll post it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: So I’ve tried assigning each label an id and tried using JavaScript to call a function when the label is clicked on, but still it doesn’t seem to work. Any other ideas?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/User9673/J5d7h/

Comment: 1. Yes, you need to keep working at it. 2. Use the debugger to step through the code slowly. 3. Pass the correct arguments to `raycaster.intersectObjects`. 4. Figure out why `cube` is not defined. 5. check the console for errors.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Three js and I seem to have hit a wall, can you or anyone else not offer any insights? I would appreciate it :)

Comment: These changes are not difficult. Make sure you understand why these changes were required. http://jsfiddle.net/J5d7h/11/ (Note: debug output is logged to the console)