# three.js 2D Text sprite labels

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm new to three.js and have some issues belonging 2D Text:

**What I want:**
I want some Labels for eg. the x,y and z-axis. The labels should always look to the camera. Maybe later they should only be shown, if their hovered but that's another topic.

**What are my issues**
I found this tutorial (which is excatly the effect I want to achieve | http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html), but it's for an old version of three.js using methods like `var spriteAlignment = THREE.SpriteAlignment.topLeft;`. I found this workaround ([THREE.SpriteAlignment showing up as undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601102/three-spritealignment-showing-up-as-undefined)) but it's not clear for me how I could use the new approach for my needs.

**What I'm looking for**
Maybe you could help me name that thing I was searching for or come up with a short approach.

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351835/clickable-sprite-labels#comment35916361_23351835 is enough to get you started. If you have trouble, show a live example of your code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Text Sprites are nice, but if you use more then thousand of it it can slow down everything because of the GPU.

There is a "better" way, create the Sprite as Canvas, here is a function that I use too for it:

```
    function makeTextSprite( message, parameters )
    {
        if ( parameters === undefined ) parameters = {};
        var fontface = parameters.hasOwnProperty("fontface") ? parameters["fontface"] : "Arial";
        var fontsize = parameters.hasOwnProperty("fontsize") ? parameters["fontsize"] : 18;
        var borderThickness = parameters.hasOwnProperty("borderThickness") ? parameters["borderThickness"] : 4;
        var borderColor = parameters.hasOwnProperty("borderColor") ?parameters["borderColor"] : { r:0, g:0, b:0, a:1.0 };
        var backgroundColor = parameters.hasOwnProperty("backgroundColor") ?parameters["backgroundColor"] : { r:255, g:255, b:255, a:1.0 };
        var textColor = parameters.hasOwnProperty("textColor") ?parameters["textColor"] : { r:0, g:0, b:0, a:1.0 };

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.font = "Bold " + fontsize + "px " + fontface;
        var metrics = context.measureText( message );
        var textWidth = metrics.width;

        context.fillStyle   = "rgba(" + backgroundColor.r + "," + backgroundColor.g + "," + backgroundColor.b + "," + backgroundColor.a + ")";
        context.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + borderColor.r + "," + borderColor.g + "," + borderColor.b + "," + borderColor.a + ")";

        context.lineWidth = borderThickness;
        roundRect(context, borderThickness/2, borderThickness/2, (textWidth + borderThickness) * 1.1, fontsize * 1.4 + borderThickness, 8);

        context.fillStyle = "rgba("+textColor.r+", "+textColor.g+", "+textColor.b+", 1.0)";
        context.fillText( message, borderThickness, fontsize + borderThickness);

        var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas) 
        texture.needsUpdate = true;

        var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false } );
        var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
        sprite.scale.set(0.5 * fontsize, 0.25 * fontsize, 0.75 * fontsize);
        return sprite;  
    }
```

Comment: Where does the `roundRect` function come from? Could you include a link to the library or the function code? THX!

Comment: I think it was a function by Lee Stemkoski, check out his Website there a lot of nice examples.

Comment: function roundRect(ctx, x, y, w, h, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + r, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w - r, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + r);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - r);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h);
    ctx.lineTo(x + r, y + h);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, y + h - r);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + r);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + r, y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

Comment: How did you determine the constants in `sprite.scale.set(0.5 * fontsize, 0.25 * fontsize, 0.75 * fontsize);`?

Comment: this code helped a lot, but instead of:
```sprite.scale.set(0.5 * fontsize, 0.25 * fontsize, 0.75 * fontsize);```
I used:
```sprite.scale.set(0.002 * canvas.width, 0.0025 * canvas.height);```
this way I get perfectly scaled text no matter how long or short the text is.

Comment: the original example is at:
https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html
if you are looking for it.

Answer (score 3):

I've published a module on NPM that does that for you: https://github.com/gamestdio/three-text2d

It allows you to have an `Object3D` with rendered text without dealing with canvas manually.

**Example:**

```
var Text2D = require('three-text2d').Text2D

var text = new Text2D("Hello world!", { align: textAlign.right, font: '30px Arial', fillStyle: '#000000', antialias: true })
scene.add(text)
```

Comment: How do you set the 3d position of the text in the above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SpriteText object. See example of using [sprites_text](https://raw.githack.com/anhr/commonNodeJS/master/SpriteText/Examples/SpriteText.html).

Example of code:

```
var spriteText = new THREE.SpriteText({ text: 'Hello world!' });
scene.add( spriteText );
```

[Source](https://github.com/anhr/commonNodeJS/tree/master/SpriteText).

Comment: Both links are dead

Comment: Links was fixed