# How to render flat text in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a library I'm working on that's supposed to display graphs. It'd be nice to include a way to label the vertices with a parameterized text, but unfortunately, I'm stuck.

My scene consists of boxes and lines. Below is how I render the box, and I'd like to know how to render a short text beneath it.

```
Graph.prototype.add_vertex = function(options){
  var v = new Vertex(this.vertex_id_spawn++, options);
  v.paint(this.scene);
  this.V[v.id] = v;

  return v;
};
```

As you can see, Vertex relies on paint to draw itself to the screen.

```
Vertex.prototype.paint = function(scene){
  this.object = new Cube(scene, this.options.cube);
  scene.add(this.object);
};
```

and the Cube function:

```
var Cube = function(scene, options){
  if(options === undefined){
    options = {};
  }

  if(options.width === undefined){
    options.width = 3;
  }
  if(options.height === undefined){
    options.height = 3;
  }
  if(options.depth === undefined){
    options.depth = 3;
  }
  if(options.color === undefined){
    options.color = 0x00ccaa;
  }

  if(options.wireframe === undefined){
    options.wireframe = false;
  }

  var geometry, material, material_args;
  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(
    options.width,
    options.height,
    options.depth
  );
  geometry.dynamic = true;

  if(options.texture !== undefined){

    material_args = { 
      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( options.texture )
    };

  }else{
    material_args = { 
      color: options.color,
      wireframe: true
    };
  }

  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( material_args );

  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  var scale = 2;
  cube.position = new THREE.Vector3(
    Math.random() * scale, Math.random() * scale,
    Math.random() * scale
  );
  cube.matrixAutoUpdate = true;

  scene.add(cube);
  return cube;
};
```

The full code is available at https://github.com/thwee-alchemist/fourd.js/blob/gh-pages/lib/fourd.js

I've been stuck on the label problem forever, and would welcome any suggestions.

**Edit** In the meantime, I've tried creating a canvas context filled with text, to get the dataURL, but to no avail. I passed the dataURL to the ImageLoader, to the map parameter of the texture which is what I do with regular vertices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three.js 2D Text sprite labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514274/three-js-2d-text-sprite-labels)

Comment: A quick google search for "three.js labels" yeilds many results and examples