# THREE.JS Raycaster and JS "objects" instead of meshes

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, raycasting

I have an issue regarding the Raycaster model. I understand the idea and the fact that it intersects meshes, which I can transform, but for example, if I create JS objects that have an inner THREE.Object3D that groups meshes (for their UI), how can I know when the corresponding *instance* of an object is clicked?

Imagine a button. This button has several characteristics and an inner _model that holds it's THREE.js graphical form (let's say a boxGeometry and a textGeometry that build this button). When the button is added to the scene it adds its buttonInstance.getModel() to the scene, and adds itself to a repository of objects to keep a reference to it.

If I wanted to click this button, I create a raycaster and get the intersecting objects from an array of "buttons" (Objects 3D or Meshes that represent this object).

But how do I fire an event or interact with the button instance itself? I have the mesh but can't get the idea on how to link it with the instance itself.

Any clues? I've searched a lot about raycasting in THREE, but all the examples relate to changing colors or positions of meshes.

```
    _raycaster.setFromCamera(new THREE.Vector2(0,0), _camera);
    _activeBtns = _raycaster.intersectObjects(_buttons, true);
    _activeBtns[0].object.parent.position.set(curPos.x, curPos.y, curPos.z-.2); // alter position of the Object3D that holds textMesh and BoxMesh
```

But how do I even know which button is this one that has been 'clicked' if all buttons have two meshes and I dont see a way of idetifying them once they are in the scene?

Thanks

d

Comment: You can add a name or type or any other field to the mesh before adding it to scene `mesh.name = 'button' or mesh.type = 'text'` and later check `if(_activeBtns[0].name === 'button'`)

Comment: @uhara Do not overwrite the `type` property of a three.js object. Use `userData`, instead: `mesh.userData.type = 'text'`.

Comment: @diekus See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800150/catch-the-click-event-on-a-specific-mesh-in-the-renderer/12808987#12808987

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the correction, unfortunately I can't edit my comment anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@uhara, @WestLangley. In the end I opted to 'bind' them by the uuid that the mesh has in the scene, since the abstract object has access to the mesh also.