# Call a function on clicking text loaded with 'new THREE.FontLoader'

Tags: three.js

I have 3D text that is created by `new THREE.FontLoader()`:

```
const loader1 = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader1.load(
  // resource URL
  './fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json',

  // onLoad callback
  (font) => {
    const textGeometry1 = new THREE.TextBufferGeometry(
      "A",
      {
        font: font,
        size: 0.6,
        height: 0.1,
        curveSegments: 20,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 0.015,
        bevelSize: 0.02,
        bevelOffset: 0,
        bevelSegments: 50

      }
    )
    const textMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'black' })
    const text1 = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry1, textMaterial1)
    text1.position.set(15.2, 0.2, 6.7)
    text1.rotation.set(0, 0.8, 0)
    scene.add(text1);
  }
);
```

How can I call function once this text is clicked? I tried to work with mesh but seems like it does not work or I am doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried using a Raycaster? https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=ray#api/en/core/Raycaster

Comment: I believe this question has been asked before here: [catch the click event on a specific mesh in the renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800150/catch-the-click-event-on-a-specific-mesh-in-the-renderer)