# Efficient Alternatives to three.interaction for rotated canvas

Tags: three.js, css-transforms, raycasting, interaction

### Background

---

I'm using `three.js` for a 3D-Website, and to detect clicks I used `three.interaction`, which worked correctly, but was very unefficient and on devices with weaker hardware it was getting really laggy.

I replaced it with a detection system that uses `Raycaster` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808987/12208261) answer). This new method is **efficient**, but the problem with it is that I'm also transforming the canvas plane (*see image below*), which makes the mouse location and raycast calculation wrong. For example, when you click to the right of the object, it counts it as a click (though this is a false alarm!)

The CSS transformation used to rotate the canvas is

```
transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5);
```

### The Question

---

1. Is there a way to correct the calculation from the linked answer to make it take the plane transformation into account?
2. Alternatively, is there another (**Efficient!**) way to do what I want? That is, detect clicks on objects, on a transformed plane as described in the `css` code?

### Appendix

---

[image]

**Side Note:** My project is quite big, so it's hard to create a minimal reproducable piece of code, if I'm able to create one I'll edit the question and add it.

Comment: Your Raycasting method probably uses `event.clientX / Y` to get the current mouse coordinates on your flat window. But if you rotate, translate & scale your canvas, then you'll need to take all those transformations into account to get the new modified XY positions, which is a very complicated process. You have a pretty powerful 3D library that could perform these transformations for you, why not use those and leave the canvas alone?

Comment: @Marquizzo I can't leave the canvas alone since part of the design of the website is to rotate the canvas as seen in the picture, and to it's right put a menu. As far as I can tell, all the transformation seen here are linear transformation, but the only problem for me would be to determine which transformations affect the calculation (for example, does the scaling/perspective affect it), and how shoudl I treat the units of `1300px` (for example, I know `20deg` need to be converted to radians for any calculation)

Comment: I've never tried doing this for a rotated canvas, and I pressume it would take me hours to get it right. Maybe you could try adding the [`mousemove` event to the canvas element directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) with `canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {});` then see what you get with `event.clientX`? The docs say it gives you the coordinates in "local (DOM Content) coordinates", so maybe it'll take the transforms into consideration?

Comment: @Marquizzo all my `eventListeners` are of the canvas. I don't know how to check though if the coordinates are local. Any idea? I can tell you that while the canvas is **untransformed**, when clicking on some location I get a value of `~1200`, but when **transformed** the value is 700, so it's not the same